# JPA java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [xxx] did not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

While executing the NamedNativeQuery using JPA i got below error message,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [pymtRefNP] did not exist
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.findParameterRegistration(BaseQueryImpl.java:486)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:603)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:163)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:32).....
```

Query:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "update", query = "UPDATE TX_XX_XXX SET CHQ_NO = :chqNoNP , STATUS_CODE = :statusCodeNP  WHERE PYMT_REF = :pymtRefNP AND CUST_ID = :custIdNP  AND COUNTRY_CODE = :countryCodeNP  AND CITY_CODE = :cityCodeNP")
```

Parameters Value:

```
    paramValues.put("pymtRefNP", bean.getPymtRef());
    paramValues.put("chqNoNP", bean.getChqNo());
    paramValues.put("statusCodeNP", 65);
    paramValues.put("custIdNP", bean.getCustId());
    paramValues.put("countryCodeNP", bean.getCountryCode());
    paramValues.put("cityCodeNP", bean.getCityCode());
```

I googled last two days regard that issue but i am not get any clear view.
Notes: I verified this query in sql editor which working perfectly.
So, anyone kindly help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you verify the type of data of the attibute pymtRefNP is equivalent to the column data?

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. **To find out what is the real problem**, I changed the query to not use parameter:

```
 "UPDATE TX_XX_XXX SET CHQ_NO = " + variable + " WHERE PYMT_REF = " + 
     key + "";
```

After to this, a receive a new message informing that the **model is not mapped**.

Fixing the **model package** every thing works fine.